# DATEDIFF and Leap Years for datetimeoffset fields in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff, leap-year

I use SQL Server 2008 R2. I should calculate difference in days between two datetimeoffset fields, and I did this as:

```
DATEDIFF(day, CAST(P.Birthdate as datetime), CAST(R.TimeOn as datetime))
```

What is the best way to calculate the difference including Leap Years? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Doing that you get the real difference in days, including Feb 29th if there was one. What problem are you having?

Comment: Thank you very much. Best regards, alenan2013

Comment: So you didn't actually have any issue? :D I honestly think that testing your code yourself would have been easier than posting the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its already working my friend, since 2016 is a leap year, lets try to check the difference between February 29 2016 and March 01 2016

```
select DATEDIFF(day,'2016-02-29','2016-03-01')
```

If you can see, the result will be 1, meaning DATEDIFF is working with leap year already.

Comment: Thank you very much. Best regards,alenan2013